# how use Positioning properties website

Tags: css, positioning, html

Im trying to build a website but im getting confused when applying the position properties to it.. 
1.-I want to create a navigation bar at the top that uses 20% of the website page and width:100% and fixed position
2.- under the navigation bar is there the image slider with some pictures with width 100% and height 60% of the webpage.
3.- under that should come the footer with width 100% and height 20% but i want that you can scroll a little bit down.

so i tryed something like this.. suggestions would be really apreciated.. im defining width and heights in % because i want to resize webpage if browser window is resized

thanks!

```
<head>
  <style>

.body {
margin: 0 0 0 0;

    .navigation {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    position:fixed;
    }

    .slider{
    position: absolute;
    top:20%
    height:60%;
    width:100%
    background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    .footer{
    position:relative;
    top:80%;
    color:lightblue;
    height:20%;
    width:100%
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="navigation">
        </div>

        <div class="slider">
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle link to make this a little more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have this correct, except for a few typos and the missing magical `html, body: 100%` which gives you a point of reference to define heights from.

- You have `.body` but should have just `body`
- You're missing two `;`s in the `.slider` styles causing other styles to be ommitted
- You define the height of `.slider` as 20% but you want it 60%.
- You have `color: lightBlue` instead of `background: lightBlue` in the `.footer` styles

This is what you need:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
  position:fixed;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  height:20%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  top: 80%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/tasux/1)

Note:  Not too sure what you mean about wanting a bit of a scroll, but you can make the footer more than 20% if you really want it to scroll.

Comment: Thank you! that helped :) .. i would vote for your answer but my reputation is yet to low